# What are these unfamiliar lines in the C preprocessed file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, compilation, gnu

This is an output of the GNU cpp on a Hello World program in C. I am wondering what do these lines mean? **# Number Header_File_Location [Numbers]**

```
# 1 "hello.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "hello.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 374 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
# 385 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 386 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
# 375 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 398 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h" 1 3 4
# 10 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h" 1 3 4
# 11 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h" 2 3 4
# 399 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4





# 1 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h" 1 3 4
# 212 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/stddef.h" 3 4
typedef long unsigned int size_t;
# 34 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4

# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h" 2 3 4


typedef unsigned char __u_char;
typedef unsigned short int __u_short;
typedef unsigned int __u_int;
typedef unsigned long int __u_long;
```

Are these some kind of dependencies? If yes, then on what? Line numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are *line number directives*, and tells the compiler what line and file the next part of the source in the [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) come from.

That's how the compiler can report errors in included header files after preprocessing.

Answer (score 6):

From gcc [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html):

> Source file name and line number information is conveyed by lines of
> the form
>
> ```
>  # linenum filename flags
> ```
>
> These are called linemarkers. They are inserted as needed into the output (but never within a string or
> character constant). They mean that the following line originated in
> file filename at line linenum. filename will never contain any
> non-printing characters; they are replaced with octal escape
> sequences.
>
> After the file name comes zero or more flags, which are ‘1’, ‘2’, ‘3’,
> or ‘4’. If there are multiple flags, spaces separate them. Here is
> what the flags mean:
>
> ‘1’ This indicates the start of a new file.
>
> ‘2’ This indicates returning to a file (after having included another file).
>
> ‘3’ This
> indicates that the following text comes from a system header file, so
> certain warnings should be suppressed.
>
> ‘4’ This indicates that the
> following text should be treated as being wrapped in an implicit
> extern "C" block.